# How to remote debug console.log

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, remote-debugging

Problem: when developing an Ionic2 app, I would like to see the console.log messages generated on my IPhone but I do not have a Mac or I do have one but found that the web inspector feature sucks.

Note this is applicable to any kind of remote javascript, not only to Angular/ionic.

This is a Q&A style question, meaning I'll provide the answer below because I think it's very useful for lots of people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is a hook into your javascript that will intercept all console.log and errors and send them to a server.

Place the following code into your index.html page:

```
<script>
// Function that will call your webserver
logToServer = function(consoleMsg) {
    // only do this if on device
    if (window.cordova) {
        let jsonTxt = customStringify(consoleMsg);
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET", 'http://yourserver/console2server.php?msg=' + jsonTxt, true); //async
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
}

// Test if you receive this on the server
logToServer("OPENING IONIC APP");

// intercept console logs
(function () {
    var oldLog = console.log;
    console.log = function (message) {
        // DO MESSAGE HERE.
        logToServer(message);
        oldLog.apply(console, arguments);
    };
})();

// intecept errors
if (window && !window.onerror) {
    window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
        logToServer(errorMsg);
        logToServer(errorObj);
        return false;
    }
}

// this is optional, but it avoids 'converting circular structure' errors
customStringify = function (inp) {
    return JSON.stringify(inp, function (key, value) {
        if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
            if (cache.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
                // Circular reference found, discard key
                console.log("circular dep found!!");
                return;
            }
            // Store value in our collection
            cache.push(value);
        }
        return value;
    });
}
</script>
```

On the server side, I use PHP but you could use whatever you want:

```
<?php
//allow CORS request
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if(isset($_GET['msg'])) {
    //you can also log to a file or whatever, I just log to standard logs
    error_log("[CONSOLE.LOG] ".json_decode($_GET['msg'], true));
}
?>
```

Happy debugging!